# c++ how to make vector store bitsets?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, bitset

So basically I want to store `std::bitset<128>` within `std::vector<>`.

I have tried this:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> myVector;
```

But compiler complains about invalid template parameters. How can I fix this and can I add this type into a `typedef` for later use?

EDIT: Indeed my compiler seems to use `C++03` as its default standard and I had to use `vector<bitset<128> >` for this to work with current settings.

Comment: What compiler/version/arguments are you using? This is valid code in C++11 but not in older versions.

Comment: [It works fine...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8476f76aebbded5) (though [in C++03 you have to write `> >` not `>>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d06985669d6a691))

Comment: @KonradRudolph I use gcc g++ version 4.9.2 in ubuntu 14.2 lts.

Comment: You need to present a proper [testcase](http://sscce.org) for "my code doesn't work" problems. Here you do not show a program and you do not show an error message.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to try that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's weird that the error message just says that "Invalid template parameters at: file.cpp line x."

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer: Why is it "weird"? The compiler cannot magically divine what you intended to, but didn't, write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it works, even with a `typedef`.

But note that you need c++11 (-std=c++11) to use **two right adjacent angle brackets** in your declaration.

```
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    typedef std::vector<std::bitset<128>> Bitset_vec;
    Bitset_vec v;
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have support for c++11, add a space between the brackets :

```
typedef std::vector<std::bitset<128> > Bitset_vec;
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/decae0c64a8b251c) (note the -std=c++11 option)

Comment: Would you recommend to switch from `C++03` to `C++11` standard?

Comment: Let's not generalise. There are many circumstances under which switching is not worthwhile.

Comment: What's with all-caps for type names? Yikes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah I don't know I'm tired, small caps back.

Comment: If you are not using C++11, place a space between the right angle brackets:  `std::vector<std::bitset<128> >`.